# Can't get AVD working with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I used to use the emulator frequently when I used Eclipse with little problems.  Now that I have been using Android Studio for about eight months I just now have need to use the emulator again for the first time with AS.

I can't get it to do anything.  It just sits there and does nothing.  The same project runs just fine on both of my test phones (LG G4, Samsung Galaxy S3).  The emulator displays, black screen with the word "android" showing.  it will sit there like that all day and do nothing.  I built two other AVDs - same thing.

The monitor window in AS shows the following...

C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -scale 0.25 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd LG_G4_API_22
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 2048MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1536MB.
emulator: device fd:944
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 0 0 360 640
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check

My AVD specs are as follows...
[image: here]

my build.gradle is as follows...
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.deanblakely.findmykids"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
Hope someone has a clue as to what's going on.
Thanks, Dean

Comment: 1) Update to Android Studio to 2.0 and try it there by following this tutorial: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/emulator 2) Try [Genymonion](https://genymotion.com) instead, if "1" didn't help. Good luck!

Comment: Might I suggest you try Genymotion: https://www.genymotion.com
I find it to be more extensible than the AS AVDs and it even contains an IDE plugin.

Comment: Konstantin: are you saying that the emulator does not work with AS 1.5.1?  That what I am experiencing is normal? That I have to use software from the canary channel if I want to use the emulator?

Comment: Genymotion requires an Oracle virtual machine that wants a 32gig disk and an entire operating system installed on it - too much!

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your SDK has the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) installed or updated, this can make a real difference also remember that AVD creates emulators not simulators so it is emulating a real device, so depending on your pc processor and RAM memory will impact to the performance, Genymotion is a great alternative because it works with Virtual Box

Comment: as you can see, this line is displayed in the log: HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode creating window 0 0 360 640 emulator.  I think that means it is running ok.  no?