# AVD in android studio showing black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

If I run the emulator in Android studio it shows a black screen.I have no idea why this happens.I have tried x86_64 and x86. I am running pixel 4 with Google play store With API Version 29.My Log File is linked and I have tried reinstalling android studio.

Log:https://drive.google.com/file/d/124k4cjr3APasLXrv6MMMtvG-HgaEk4Mn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried updating Android Emulator from SDK tools? Also, check the google api system images of the targeted api sdk is installed.

Comment: I dont have much experience in android can you tell how to do what you told?

Comment: In Android Studio go to SDK Manager.  Once there you should check under Android 10 (because you choose API 29) if Android SDK Platform 29 is checked. Do not forget to check "Show Package Details" before that. Regarding the Android emulator update, this is shown through a minus - signal, instead of a check signal. A minus means that an update is required, just by clicking on the minus signal.

Comment: Also, try out the following: verify if your SDK has the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) installed or updated - see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139805/cant-get-avd-working-with-android-studio

Comment: Tried both of them no change any other troubleshooting tips?

Comment: Also the disk space of the avd is 583 mb not 1.1 gb as i have seen in tutorials

Comment: Try out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KdGmg4mTpI) tutorial. Maybe it can help.